# Android Recycler/List . How to implement explode animation like shown by image below

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

Can someone please help me on how to implement explode animation like shown by image below.

[image: GIF image from Keep Application]

This is what i have achieved so far. Using shared elements transition

[image]

Comment: So all you want is the different animation? Could you show your code?

Comment: Yes it's a different animation i wanted. Basically i was hoping to get help or direction on how to implement animation that is exactly like first gif.